# Allow experienced users to skip the "New Question" UI

Tags: discussion, ask-question-form

I have over 1K questions on SE/SOF family so might not want to see the extra fanfare of the newish design (as of 9/26/19) that seems directed towards new users:

[image]
Is it possible to see the more streamlined interface that we had until yesterday?

**Update** In response to a question about "what is the extra fanfare":   The entire top bar is higher now /takes more space - to make space for the robot and those question balloons. In addition the entire right hand nav area explaining how to ask a question: that is a big waste of real estate for experienced users. The screen real estate is no longer dedicated to the content of the question being entered.

Another update (11 days later).  Asking a question now feels like being transported to nursery school.

Comment: Why do non-teams members see the callout to "public"?

Comment: That is the streamlined interface. It just includes updated graphics and sidebar.

Comment: It's filled with so much noise, it feels more like an attempt to scare people off.

Comment: "Streamlined": it is not so compared to the prior interface.

Comment: It’s impossible making any change without annoying someone. I find it OK, but I don’t  ask questions often. And if it results in better quality questions; I’ll take even if I the extra graphics gave me seizures.

Comment: Why not take a look at how many questions a user has already asked: that's why i mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: @javadba because that would require maintaining two solutions that serve the same purpose.

Comment: You are participating in an A/B test, only some SO users see this page.  They'll measure how often you click the robot.

Comment: Because it would add a new path for testing and maintenance; and it may not be worth it if the benefit for newer users outweigh the possible bother for users with more experience.

Comment: This change literally does nothing but make it look better. the blog post seemed to indicate it was a more significant change.

Comment: That's a clear choice of preferring new users over frequent ones: why force a choice like that?

Comment: How is making something look better a preferential change? It's purely opinion on what is "better".

Comment: This is much busier and looks worse.

Comment: Because there are more potential “new” users out there than “old” users in here. But it’s not about that; it’s about improving question quality. Many “old” users suck at asking questions as well.

Comment: Nothing in this change would help people ask questions better.

Comment: By your own admission you do not ask questions often: I do and why put this extra baggage on the screen.  Basically you are saying that opinions/preferences of frequent users count little.

Comment: Well, that’s the stated objective. I’m sure they tested the design and have an idea about why it would make an impact. I know nothing of the subject and I find it easy to ignore a few extra robots. So I’m OK with SO trying new things

Comment: I think it's good SE focuses a bit on new users (as long as that doesn't directly contradict SE's mission), and I think an update to the page is due, but this is just noisy. They should've kept it simple at least. Using that page feels awkward

Comment: Every time anything changes meta moans and complains. I say let’s give the change some time to see how it feels and if it works or not. The important things are the tools for quality rating and curation; a slight adjustment in UI should not be the thing to make a huge deal about, IMO.

Comment: I don't mind that it changed. But to pretend it's far more significant than it is, and to continue tieing the Teams UI into the base product, it's troubling.

Comment: @javadba can you describe what you mean by "extra fanfare"? I can guess, but it will be helpful to me if you can say a bit more if you're willing.

Comment: And how many times did you click the robot? ;)

Comment: @MeganRisdal Maybe having extra bells and whistles does not distract you - it does to me and de-focuses on writing the question. The new gui uses real estate that could otherwise be left blank or put other actually useful information.   How much time do you spend writing questions - pls take that into account vs others for whom this may be a more frequent activity.

Comment: "extra fanfare" : the entire top bar is higher now /takes more space - to make space for the robot and those question balloons.  In addition there is that whole right hand nav area explaining how to ask a question: that is a big waste of real estate. The screen real estate is no longer dedicated to the content of the  question being entered.

Comment: @MeganRisdal  Having a minimal interface to focus on the task at hand is one reason for google search's popularity: pls allow for those of us that feel this minimalism were important and have spent much time on this site as a result.

Comment: @MeganRisdal "and how many times did you click the robot" Using that as the primary A/B test criteria is a poor qualifier in terms of accounting for usability concerns. It only says whether the page were completely non-functional or not -ie an experienced user were so confused as to unintentionally end up in a full help screen. It does not idenfity that the page is now significantly less usable than previously.

Comment: FWIW when I read the blog, I interpreted it as this view becoming the new asking view *for everyone*, not just new users. Maybe I misread it, though. Also FWIW I agree that the fanfare is too Neopets-esque (which would take more than a comment to fully unpack) and I will be removing the content with user styles/user scripts as soon as it is presented to me. EDIT - I see it's live for all users--time to open up Stylus...

Comment: Also to be fair the traditional asking UI also shows a right-hand side bar with links and guidance on how to ask, it just said different stuff. So that part is not really significantly different.

Comment: @javadba Okay, thank you for elaborating. FYI the robot click thing was not serious, don't worry. :) We'll be toning down the illustration soon.

Comment: @MeganRisdal Any thoughts on when this might be changed ..  Asking a question now is like being transported to nursery school.

Comment: @javadba We've toned down the illustration some. The changes are still in A/B testing.

Comment: @MeganRisdal  Is it not possible to do what is in the title: to allow opting out ?  Why subject long time users to these "new user" approaches?

Comment: @MeganRisdal It has been a month - any idea when these changes will be rolled back (or that opt-out added)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** This evening the GUI was finally updated - to a wizard mode. *Much* better ..

[image]

***Another update*** We're back to square one?? The robot and balloons are back again.  Maybe I was seeing an **A/B test** two days ago ?? If so then yea that was better than the robots and balloons..

**Older information: applicable from Sept 2019 to late June 2020**

It has been over three months - and the last contact from the team that made the change was over two months ago. Are we stuck with .. *this* .. ?

[image]

Well given the lack of activity it seems so.

**Another update (6 months later)**  Well this request has been gathering dust. I would note:  the UI could really use a fix in the following way:

There is insufficient space provided to review the *existing* questions. I made up a new Question that is obviously already answered.

[image]

Notice that only *two* of the (many) related answers fit here.  Providing more space to view more existing questions would be a better use of screen real estate (and designer efforts..) than that robot with the answer balloons..

Comment: As always a custom blocking rule for an ad-blocker can help there somewhat.