# Ask Question: Too much distraction?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I wanted to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) but noticed that there is too much distraction with respect to the "cartoons" and the "How to ask pane". **Is there a way to hide these when asking a question?**

I also would like to suggest an alternative implementation that:

1. Gets rid of the "cartoons" on top.
2. Places the "How to ask" pane inside the question body so a user can simply follow that and edit accordingly.

Comment: [Opting for the traditional “new question” UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389830)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Glad I'm not the only one who noticed this. "Seasoned" users should have an option of seeing  the old UI. I just want to ask a question, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I [posted on this too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389438/3000206). I hope they don't decide to default that page for newer users.